# Word problem with multiple variables

Tags: word-problem

I have the following word problem:

*Bob received 21 gifts in total for his birthday. He got video games, CDs, snack bars, and sudoku books. He received 3 times as many CDs as video games, and twice as many sudoku books as snack bars. How many of each gift did he receive?*

The problem can easily be solved by testing numbers, but is there any formulaic way to do so?

EDIT: Question mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up 3 equations from the word problem.

$$V+C+A+U=21\\C=3V\\U=2A$$So we can say $$V+3V+A+2A=21\\4V+3A=21$$

From here, you cannot directly solve this without an additional piece of information, but you can guess and check how many sums of a multiple of 4 and a multiple of 3 equal 21.  One such sum is, $12+9$.  $$4(3)+3(3)=21\\9+3+3+6=21$$

Answer (score 1):

Pile the CDs and video games together. The number of items in the pile must be a multiple if what? Pile the others together. The number must be a multiple of what? You can write a Diaphontine equation for this, adding to $21$ Now if you consider divisibility by $3$ you will be guided. There are two solutions (if you don't insist that he got at least one of each thing).

Comment: We do also have that Bob definitely received all these items, though. No zeros.

Comment: @Joffan:  Good point.  I have edited in a comment to that effect.